# Add new user and password to linux via a sql database

Tags: sql, database, linux, addition

so a user enters data in a web form, data gets sent to main database table, and then a script runs periodically, like every day to then do a few tasks like adding a user to a linux system. I want to add a user with a password that was stored in the database. So far I only have this:

```
$MYSQL -e  "select name  from users registered" | sudo xargs -L 1 useradd
$MYSQL -e  "select password  users registered" | sudo xargs -L 1  passwd
```

but it seems to think the password field in the database is a username?

Comment: the 2nd select is syntactically wrong. passwd will not accept passwords on the command-line.

Comment: How could it be corrected?

Comment: It can't be corrected: passwd(1) is terminal oriented program and is designed not to accept passwords from standard input. You should also do some sanity checking for your usernames as now you're vulnerable to anything someone might be able to inject into your SQL, including, e.g. `rm -rf /`.